# Advice on repining molex 43025 20pin

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, cable, ibm-server, molex

So here's the deal, I've got a older ibm server and it only has 8 sas connections but supports additional 4 with additional board. Got the board, fairly cheap but the thing is the power cable is so rare and no-existant that people are charging £200+ for it. It's just a cheapo molex cable.

tldr; got a custom cable that is too expensive to buy but is made from cheap parts that I have but would need to repin.

The cable is a [Molex 43025 2000 (20pin)](https://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/molex-llc/0430252000/WM2492-ND/531408), it's currently a 20pin male split to two 10pin cables. What I require is a 10pin to a 10pin, already confirmed that the 10pin matches the female on motherboard and the female on the sas backplane board. So those can just be plugged together without me grinding corners etc but it appears that IBM have somewhat alternated the cables, looks like each pin on the 10pins is either a +5 pin or a -5 pin compared to another, it appears to have a pattern both ways.

I'm not exactly expert with cabling so them saying double row I image the pins go 1-10 and upper row goes 11-20. Based on that, made a [quick spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RDVpCgMpyoEzJrmMvHlp_hfMz-4eqR-VAc8fGAWs7ko) with pin shape and the cabling to the split. here;.

Because I don't have the right tools, it will be a dirty job with stripping copper and using electrical tape to connect the 2 10pin cables together to get a working cable.

Could I ask for advice on which pins I'd need to join on each of the cables to achieve this? I'm looking at this and it feels obvious but... I just want someone smarter than me to confirm what I believe.

[Actual Cable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/um088.jpg)

Thanks for taking the time to read and I hope you can help me with my predicament.

links;

https://www.digikey.co.uk/product-detail/en/molex-llc/0430252000/WM2492-ND/531408

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RDVpCgMpyoEzJrmMvHlp_hfMz-4eqR-VAc8fGAWs7ko

https://i.stack.imgur.com/um088.jpg

Comment: Just buy the proper molex cable release tool.

Comment: yeah did that afterwards, wanted to make sure it worked first, some tape  did fine, but seated them correctly afterwards and sleeved it

Answer (score 1):

Nvm, sorted it now, I was making it overly complicated, snipped them and connect 10pins 1to1, worked fine without issues. 200£ saved